# How to change the axis of the Move Tool within Edit Mode? (2.8)

Tags: modeling, transforms, axis, transform-orientation

When I enter the editing mode and move a vertex or edge, the tool's axes (gizmo) is always diagonal / sloped. When I manipulate a polygon, the Z axis follows its normal.

I can't change the Transform Orientations:

[image: Transform Orientations don't change]

How to make the move handler follow the global axes? I've already tried changing the Transform Orientations to global, local, view but nothing happens.

How to force orientation to be like this?

[image: Transform Orientations is global]

This problem only occurs with the Move Tool. When I switch Transform Orientations with Rotate and Scale Tools, it works perfectly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind. I discovered the solution. All manipulation tools have their own definition of Trasform Orientations that will only respect the TO of the viewport if it is as 'default'.

[image]

As my Move Tool was with Transform Orientations = Normal, it was no use changing the TO of the viewport. Just set to 'default' to resolve.

Thank you. I'll leave the topic to anyone who has this same problem in the future.